# how to compare IP value in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line

I have the next command in order to get my current ip address :

```
ip=$(ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}' | grep -v "127")
```

and i want to check if the ip starts with 19 or with 10, with if statement

```
if [[ $ip =~ "^19*" ]]; then some instructions; fi
```

but it does not works, i hope you help in this

Comment: `grep -v 127` is going to come back and bite you sometime when your get assigned `10.0.0.127` or seomthing.  Also, shouldn't you be checking if it starts with `10.` or `192.168.` (or the 172.whatever it is reserved range of class-C networks) rather than just `1[09]`?

Comment: yes you right, thanks

Comment: Some of the answers on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119269/how-to-get-ip-address-using-shell-script might be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your regex would check for `1`, `19`, `199`, `1999` etc., not for "19 or 10". The regex for "starts with 19 or 10" would be `^1[90]`.

Secondly, if you quote the regex, it is matched as a string, i.e., literally. You could use

```
if [[ $ip =~ ^1[90] ]]; then
```

It is good practice to store the regex in a separate variable and then use that variable, unquoted, to avoid all quoting issues:

```
re='^1[90]'
if [[ $ip =~ $re ]]; then
```

References:

- [Bash manual about conditional constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)
- BashGuide [page about patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) (see regex section)
- [Chet's FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ) at E14

Answer (score 0):

Remove double quotes around  "^19*"

and loop over $ip as it may have list of ips